# Why isn't chr() outputting the correct character?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a Caesar Cypher with Python 3 where s is the string input and k is the amount that you shift the letter. I'm currently just trying to work through getting a letter like 'z' to wrap around to equal 'B'(I know the case is wrong, I'll fix it later). However when I run caesarCipher using the the following inputs: s = 'z' and k = 2,  the line: s[n] = chr((122-ord(s[n]) + 64 + k)) causes s[n] to equal 'D'. If i adjust it down two(logically on the unicode scale this would equal 'B'), it makes s[n] = @. What am I doing wrong on that line that's causing 'B' not to be the output?

```
   def caesarCipher(s, k):
       # Write your code here
       n = 0
       s = list(s)
       while n < len(s):
           if s[n].isalpha() == True:
               if (ord(s[n].lower())+k) < 123:  
                   s[n] = (chr(ord(s[n])+k)) 
                   n += 1
               else: 
                   s[n] = chr((122-ord(s[n]) + 64 + k))
           else:
               n += 1
       s = ''.join(s)
       return s
```

Comment: You need to do a `n += 1` after that line. In that case it will output `B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add 1 to n in the test of `(ord(s[n].lower())+k) < 123` so that it would count s[n] twice or more.

Change it to

```
else:
    s[n] = chr((122 - ord(s[n]) + 64 + k))
    n += 1
```

and if you input "z" and 2, you'll get "B"

```
print(caesarCipher("z", 2))
# B
```

and if you adjust it down two, you'll get "@", which is the previous previous character of B in ASCII.

```
...
    else:
        s[n] = chr((122 - ord(s[n]) + 62 + k))
        n += 1
...
print(caesarCipher("z", 2))
# @
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That fixed it.

Comment: If you think the answer is helpful, you could accept the answer.